# Numpy: How to cast string array to float while some of the elements contain extra quoted string

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to convert string to float type by the following

```
X = arr[:,:-1].astype(np.float32)
```

However, error as below is rising

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '"53"'
```

I know this means I have some elements with extra quote in the array. 
My problem is how should I solve this. How can I convert element '"53"'  into 53 inside the array?

UPDATE 1:
Here is an example to reproduce

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([['12','13'],['"53"','44']])
a = a.astype(np.float32)
```

Comment: It would be nice if you could provide a reproducible example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try **stripping** the double quotes from the array, **then** casting to float.

Like so:

```
arr = np.char.strip(arr, '"')
X = arr[:,:-1].astype(np.float32)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `numpy.char.replace()` to perform element-wise string replace on an array of strings.

> Signature: `np.char.replace(a, old, new, count=None)`
>
> Docstring: For
>   each element in `a`, return a copy of the string with all occurrences
>   of substring `old` replaced by `new`. Calls `str.replace` element-wise.

---

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([["12","13"],['"53"',"44"]])

b = np.char.replace(a, '"', '')
c = b.astype(np.float32)
```